# backup Linux partitions from within Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, backup, grub, cloning

So I have Grub Loader installed with Windows and Debian installations.

If I use windows 7 backup to make an image backup of the drive will it also backup the other partitions and software?

In other words, if I create an image back up of the drive will it still be able to dual boot both OS after using restoring the drive

Is there software that is better suited to cloning or creating images of drives with multiple OS's with the ability to restore them?

Comment: First of all you should edit your question with additional information instead of adding a comment.

Note that Windows 7 is deprecated and has not received any security updates in over a year. It is not recommended to continue using it. Also note that the backup and restore feature of windows works on file level, not on block level and works only with NTFS partitions. Even if it would backup your linux partition, it would be highly unlikely that you would be able to boot right away due to different partition UUIDs.

Comment: @mashuptwice Thank you for your information. 
So to clarify, creating a system image using windows backup will not back up my Linux partition?

Answer (score 0):

no windows doesn't recognize the linux partitions, so no image backup will work for both on the windows side.

I guess "timeshift" is an option from the linux side if you include the other partitions in the backup, but I have no idea how that will affect the windows image.

and since dd would be stupid even for a tiny drive, I think what you're looking for is an extra drive setup  for raid.

unless you want an  image to install some where else, then I'm afraid you're out of luck.